# Bundle errors when setting up react-native in monorepo

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, metro-bundler

I'm having some issues setting up a new react-native project inside a yarn monorepo with workspaces. My root package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "mono-repo",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "web-app",
      "utils",
      "mobile-app"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/jest",
      "**/jest/**",
      "**/mocha",
      "**/mocha/**",
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**"
    ]
  },
```

When i run `yarn run-ios` the build succeeds but I get bundler errors:

```
bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `bugsnag-react-native` from `index.js`: bugsnag-react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  ../node_modules
```

the `bugsnag-react-native` folder *does* exist in the root `node_modules`

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here / how to fix it?

I'm using yarn version `1.19.0`

Comment: are you using the module bugsnag-react-native? if you are in a monorepo it could have been installed in the node_modules directory in the root not in one of the packages.